# Square matrix injectiveness

Tags: matrices

I spent half an hour just searching for this but I can't find a direct phrase claiming this. For a square matrix , if the determinant is zero does this prove that the matrix is one-to-one(injective)?

Comment: if the determinant is zero it proves that the operator associated with this matrix is *not* injective.

Comment: Do you mean the linear transformation associated to the matrix is not injective?